# Commenting in excel such that panda dont read it

Tags: python, excel, pandas, comments

I would like to implement some comments in my excel document, but i dont want panda to be able to see them as i have alot of headers that need commenting but dont want to change my entire script to include the comments when getting values from those headers..

I have though about adding a "comment header" and not reading that particular header when importing the excel document but would like a different solution, if commenting elsewhere than in the header might occur in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to read the individual sheets as dataframes using read_csv. That will let you use the "comment" arg.

e.g.

```
df = pd.read_csv("directory", comment='#')
```

You can read more here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html